# EF 4.3 saving One to Many causing errors or duplicate rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net

Really hope someone can help, as been twearing my hair out the last two nights and going no where fast! and desperately trying to get a family project going which I'm doing for no profit and its rapidly eating up my time as I'm trying to use it to learn some new technologies.

It seems this is a common issue, as found a few similar ish posts on stackoverflow etc but now seem to have guided me to a working solution.

I either get errors or duplicate rows going into the database, my simplified model is a one to many relationship. But I'm trying to store the WebsiteUserSession object in the users session to save a database hit on every page load.

Model:

```
public class WebsitePageTracking
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsiteUserSession WebsiteUserSession { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string TrackUrl { get; set; }
}

public class WebsiteUserSession
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime_Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime_LastSessionStart { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WebsitePageTracking> WebsitePageTracking { get; set; }
}
```

Then my code is as follows, a little more complex but hopefully get the idea. Note the datacontext is stored in the HttpContext.Items which was one suggestion.

```
/// <summary>
/// public method for fetching and persisting website user session
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static WebsiteUserSession GetWebsiteUserSession()
{
    // set initial variables
    Guid? websiteUserGuid = null;
    string websiteUserIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    WebsiteUserSession websiteUserSession = null;            

    // first try and get from the session
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["WebsiteUserSession"] != null)
    {
        // load the website user session, and fetch out the guid
        websiteUserSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["WebsiteUserSession"] as WebsiteUserSession;
        websiteUserGuid = websiteUserSession.Guid;

        // check to see if ip has changed, if so drop website user session
        if (websiteUserSession.IpAddress != websiteUserIpAddress)
            websiteUserSession = null;
    }
    else
    {
        // nothing so create brand new guid
        websiteUserGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    // if we don't have one which came from the session then get the website user session using guid/ip
    if (websiteUserSession == null)
        websiteUserSession = GetWebsiteUserSession((Guid)websiteUserGuid, websiteUserIpAddress);

    // if not stored in the session add that now
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["WebsiteUserSession"] == null)
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("WebsiteUserSession", websiteUserSession);

    // return back website user session object
    return websiteUserSession;
}

/// <summary>
/// gets or creates a website user session record in the database
/// </summary>
/// <param name="guid">guid generated for the website user</param>
/// <param name="ipAddress">public ip address of website user</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static WebsiteUserSession GetWebsiteUserSession(Guid guid, string ipAddress)
{
    DataContext dataContext = HttpContext.Current.Items["DataContext"] as DataContext;

    // try and fetch a user session from database
    WebsiteUserSession websiteUserSession = dataContext
        .WebsiteUserSessions
        .Where(x => x.Guid == guid && x.IpAddress == ipAddress)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (websiteUserSession != null)
    {
        // if found update last session time
        websiteUserSession.DateTime_LastSessionStart = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        // create a new website user session
        websiteUserSession = new WebsiteUserSession();
        websiteUserSession.Guid = guid;
        websiteUserSession.IpAddress = ipAddress;
        websiteUserSession.DateTime_Created = websiteUserSession.DateTime_LastSessionStart = DateTime.Now;
        dataContext.WebsiteUserSessions.Add(websiteUserSession);
    }

    // persist changes
    dataContext.SaveChanges();                

    return websiteUserSession;
}

/// <summary>
/// log a stock page view to database
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stockId">id of stock being viewed</param>
public static void LogStockPageView(int stockId)
{
    DataContext dataContext = HttpContext.Current.Items["DataContext"] as DataContext;

    WebsiteUserSession websiteUserSession = GetWebsiteUserSession();

    //dataContext.WebsiteUserSessions.Attach(websiteUserSession);
    //dataContext.Entry(websiteUserSession).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    WebsitePageTracking pageTrack = new WebsitePageTracking();
    pageTrack.WebsiteUserSession = websiteUserSession;
    pageTrack.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    pageTrack.TrackUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

    dataContext.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    dataContext.Entry(website).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    dataContext.Entry(websiteUserSession).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    //dataContext.Entry(websiteUserSession.WebsitePageTracking).State = EntityState.Detached;

    //dataContext.WebsiteUserSessions.Attach(pageTrack.WebsiteUserSession);    

    dataContext.WebsitePageTracking.Add(pageTrack);

    //dataContext.Entry(pageTrack.WebsiteUserSession).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Basically what should happen is someone browses a page, LogStockPageView() gets called which in turn gets a WebsiteUserSession entity either from the session, database or creates a new one. Then WebsitePageTracking entity is added to the database with an association to the WebsiteUserSession.

You can see all the commented lines of attempts to get this working, but I either get errors or lots of duplicate rows being inserted :(

One such error is this "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.".

Please please can someone see where I'm going wrong or even suggest better solutions? really trying to get going with EF but struggling :(

Thanks, Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code has a lot of problems because of the way how EF works. The very first problem is using session. Session will save you database queries but you will have to add a lot of special code to your application to make this work in all expected scenarios. I will use session only in scenario where my entity stored in session is never used for data modification (it is never used by EF again). You can use FK properties to avoid a lot of pain in this case.

The first problem appears in `GetWebsiteUserSession` where you return attached entity from the method. If you also have lazy loading enabled you can be quite sure that adding tracking in the next request will result in `ObjectDisposedException`. The reason is that proxied attached entity keeps internally reference to the current context which is disposed at the end of the current request. When the entity tries to load navigation property it uses that reference. It can work if you turn off proxy creation / lazy loading but the better solution can be detaching entity prior to returning it from the method because it will allow rest of your code working with only single scenario:

```
dataContext.Entry(websiteUserSession).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Be aware that detaching will empty your `WebSitePageTracking` collection. If you want to detach entity graph you must create deep clone (serialization / deserialization).

The second problem is whole `LogStockPageView`. If your current session instance is attached to the context you don't need to attach it again or change its state but you will have to do it in case of detached entity. Try this:

```
public static void LogStockPageView(int stockId)
{
    DataContext dataContext = HttpContext.Current.Items["DataContext"] as DataContext;

    WebsiteUserSession websiteUserSession = GetWebsiteUserSession();

    dataContext.WebsiteUserSessions.Attach(websiteUserSession);

    WebsitePageTracking pageTrack = new WebsitePageTracking();
    pageTrack.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    pageTrack.TrackUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

    dataContext.WebsitePageTracking.Add(pageTrack);

    // Make connection after both session and track are correctly configured and attached
    pageTrack.WebsiteUserSession = websiteUserSession;

    dataContext.SaveChanges();

    // again detach session 
    dataContext.Entry(websiteUserSession).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Your sample code also contains multiple references to other entities. Those have the same problem. If you store them in session and they are somehow related to your saving code you must deal with them as well.

If you want your `websiteUserSession` to keep whole track in the session it will become more complex because instead of detaching you will have to use entity graph cloning.

Comment: Wow, that is spot on and such a good explanation... Sorry for the sample code referencing other entities, my mistake I simplified it but forgot to take some bits out. Anyway I made your suggested changes and it works!! and things are a lot clearer now... It's past midnight here in NZ so should have gone to bed, but was interested to try your suggestions... Will go over them again tomorrow in more detail and continue with my project :) Thanks a million!!